# I'm trying to remember the name of an Outlook add-In that let you send the same email to multiple recipients simultaneously

Tags: microsoft-outlook, addons

I trialed an Outlook add-in that had a number of different functions, one of which allowed you to send the same email to multiple recipients at the same time, without doing it as a bcc.  For example, if I wanted to send the same email to Tom, Dick and Harry without having to write 3 emails, the add-in let me specify the names and the email would go to the 3 of them.  In my Sent Items folder would be 3 emails each addressed to the respective person.

The add-in might have started with an S, or an R, but I don't remember.